# Where I can find the definition of Array declarations in Java documentation?

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to create arrays in Java but when I tried to find some information about arrays and theirs declarations to better understand this part of Java, I found nothing about it in documentation.

I know two ways of array declarations:

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
int[] arr2 = new int[3];
```

I can't find a section in Java documentation that contains the above definition.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, I don't get why people would downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) on arrays.

And the authority is of course the [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html).

Comment: This doesn't address the question which is where they are in the JDK documentation, and if not why not. Tutorials contain very little info and the spec is too much for the average dev.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) for Java documentation reference(under section 10.2 Array Variables).

Also, to answer you question both the declarations are true and the difference lies in the **new** operator.

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
```

In the above code you are assigning array type values to a variable and it uses memory from the variable pool space of JRE.

```
int[] arr2 = new int[3];
```

Whereas this one creates a new object, uses memory in java heap to store values and assign it to the variable. Also, the **new** operator will automatically initialize the array to zero (for numeric types), false (for boolean), or null (for reference types).

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is the online documentation on arrays for the Java Platform. I believe this is the standard edition 7.

Also, more information can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) as well on how to use Java Arrays. Here you can find/learn everything on Java (at a beginner/intermediate level).

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search brought me without problems to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: This is not the same thing